# Multicol - don't wrap

Tags: page-breaking, multicol

I have two-columned page by multicol:

```
   \begin{multicols}{2}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
   \end{multicols}
```

It there any way to ban wrapping to the second column. What I mean is, that I need one whole pararaph in the first column and I don't want to wrap it.

Comment: Is the contents of the `multicols` environment regular text? Or does it form part of something special (like a ToC)?

Comment: It is regular text.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do not want any column balancing: just use `multicols*` as the environment.

If you do want balancing but control the breakpoint then `\columnbreak` will allow you to set them explicitly as needed.

If you just want to ensure that column breaks are happening only between paragraphs then you could set

```
\interlinepenalty=10000
```

inside the multicols environment. However, for that to work you need the latest version of the package (1.8a), which so far is only at [the SVN site for LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/latex2e-public/required/tools/multicol.dtx). With older versions of multicol this might result in column overflows, as the algorithm doesn't expect that there are nearly no breakpoints. See also the discussion in "[multicols-not-wrapping-to-2nd-column-properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20532/multicols-not-wrapping-to-2nd-column-properly/38787#38787)" which let to this new version.

Answer (score 9):

Issuing a `\columnbreak` is usually the way to force a break from one column to the next. As such, document elements prior to it should stay together and not wrap to the next column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[3] \columnbreak
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

This works, regardless of the length of the respective documents elements (to see, switch `\lipsum[3]` and `\lipsum[2]`).