# how to make ragged bottoms of columns in multicols when preventing page breaks?

Tags: sectioning, multicol

The setup: I need to use multicols for say 3 columns where I have many small sections. I noticed that some sections are broken in the middle and end up wrapping to the next column, which I do not want.

After some research (i.e googling) found that adding `\interlinepenalty=10000` prevents this. And it does. [Multicol - don't wrap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37942/multicol-dont-wrap)

But instead of having the gaps at the bottom of the columns (ragged bottoms, or whatever the correct name for it), the columns end up with large empty space in between, which does not look good.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

generated using:

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt} %column thicnkess 
\setlength{\columnsep}{5.0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}     
\interlinepenalty=10000
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[3]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[4]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

removing `\interlinepenalty=10000` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which I do not want since section is flowing across columns.

Removing the star version does not help either. One must use `\interlinepenalty=10000` to prevent page break inside a section. But then the problem are those large gaps in between sections.

Then I used `samepage` to wrap each section inside it in the hope it will help. But this result was more strange. I must have done something wrong here:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the code for the above

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt} %column thicnkess 
\setlength{\columnsep}{5.0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}     
%\interlinepenalty=10000

\begin{samepage}
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\end{samepage}

\begin{samepage}
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\end{samepage}

\begin{samepage}
\section{some section}
\lipsum[3]
\end{samepage}

\begin{samepage}
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\end{samepage}

\begin{samepage}
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\end{samepage}

\begin{samepage}
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\end{samepage}

\begin{samepage}
\section{some section}
\lipsum[4]
\end{samepage}

\begin{samepage}
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\end{samepage}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

What is the correct way to prevent page breaks in the middle of sections, but have the extra space be at the bottom and not in between?

Using Tex live 2013 on Linux. (ps. one day, I need to learn how to use Latex to make copies code fragment to I do not copy paste same code again and again).

Comment: Try adding `\raggedcolumns` before or after `\begin{multicols}{3}` in your first MWE (works with both the starred and non starred version of multicol.

Comment: @dcmst thanks that worked. If you like to add this as answer so I can accept and close this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The desired effect can be achieved using the `\raggedcolumns` macro:

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt} %column thicnkess 
\setlength{\columnsep}{5.0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\raggedcolumns     %new code
\interlinepenalty=10000
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[3]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[4]
\section{some section}
\lipsum[75]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]