# columnseprule overhangs the type area

Tags: multicol

**Related Question**

- [multicols not wrapping to 2nd column
  properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20532/multicols-not-wrapping-to-2nd-column-properly)

**Aim:**

I develop a din-a4 questionnaire and want to typeset the questions in a two column layout. As a constraint i don't want columnbreaks or pagebreaks inside a test item. In addition the columns should be separated by a rule.

**Current status**:

Unfortunately the `\columnseprule` hangs over the bottom of the type area.

The following MWE illustrates this (look at the bottom of the first output page):

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{1.5ex}
\setlength\parsep{1.5\parskip}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}

\newcommand{\drawbox}[2][1] {
   \adjustbox{
     minipage=\linewidth,
     padding=1ex #1 0ex #1,
     center,
     bgcolor=red!20,
     cfbox=red
  }{%
     #2
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
   \foreach \i in {1,...,3} {
      \drawbox[17em]{Item \i}\par
   }
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image][image]

**Question**

How can i limit the `\columseprule` to the typearea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harrish showed a solution using a different package, but with respect to your initial example all that is needed is using the latest version of the `multicol`. I haven't tried to check when that got fixed or what the problem was with the version you used (might have been just with the latest update that reached CTAN just the other day) but if you use that (version 1.8l) then you get

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tcolorbox` instead of `adjustbox` then there won't be any problem.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,pgffor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showframe}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{1.5ex}
\setlength\parsep{1.5\parskip}

\begin{document}

\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
   \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
      \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!20,colframe=red,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt]
        \lipsum[\i]
      \end{tcolorbox}
   }
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The details of how to tweak the box style are available in `tcolorbox` manual.

Comment: Indeed, `\columnsep` is limited to the type area now. Do you know whether `tcolorbox` takes any precautions for this case internally? Best regards

Comment: @user1146332 I am not so sure of the precautions taken by `tcolorbox` but for sure, it won't trouble you in this case. :)